# Plano-convex lenses

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

When the spherical side of a planoconvex lens is towards the source we will see reduced aberrations normally we use it for the beam collimation. When we use two planoconvex lenses configuration why we dont use back to back oriented like a single planoconvex? why do we use them as in the second picture below. What will happen if we will use as in the first picture ? Is it only to reduce aberrations ? In practice where do we use the configuration in second picture ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The arrangement is to reduce aberrations. The curved face introduces more aberration so it is normally better to have the flatter face produce most of the ray refraction power. If you reverse the lenses, there will be more aberration.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to distribute the refractive power on both surfaces of each lens to reduce aberrations. What matters is the angle of incidence of the rays with respect to the normal at the interfaces: the smaller the angle, the closer to the paraxial approximation (that predicts a point-like image).

If you orient the planar surface towards the collimated beam, no refraction occur there and the angles on the other surface have to be greater, which induce more aberration.