# Bi-convex or plano-convex for shrinking a close image?

Tags: optics

I have a flat image that is being uniformly irradiated that I would like to enlarge, it will be irradiated using one wavelength so chromatic aberrations aren't an issue. Which of the two lens types would reduce spherical aberrations.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow the question, but in general, if the object and the image are at similar distances from the lens, use a biconvex lens, while if one is much farther away than the other, use a plano-convex lens and let the curved side of the lens face whichever is farther away. This approach minimizes spherical aberrations by making the difference between the wavefront and lens curvatures as similar as possible on both faces of the lens.

Comment: Does the uniformity of the light intensity across the image not affect which you would use?

Comment: I don't think so, unless I am misunderstanding something about this setup. An extended object (with uniform illumination or otherwise) can be thought of as an array of point sources of light. The rule of thumb described above minimizes spherical aberrations in the re-imaging of these point-sources. Anael's response on this earlier plano-convex lens explains the reasoning behind this rule: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/plano-convex-lenses.

Comment: Feel free to answer with that and I'll mark it a correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tranferring my comments on the original post to the answer section, as the OP has confirmed that they do in fact address his situation:)

In general, if the object and the image are at similar distances from the lens, use a biconvex lens, while if one is much farther away than the other, use a plano-convex lens and let the curved side of the lens face whichever is farther away. This approach minimizes spherical aberrations by making the difference between the wavefront and lens curvatures as similar as possible on both faces of the lens.

An extended object (with uniform illumination or otherwise) can be thought of as an array of point sources of light. The rule of thumb described above minimizes spherical aberrations in the re-imaging of these point-sources. Anael's response on this [earlier plano-convex lens question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/plano-convex-lenses) explains the reasoning behind this rule.